# Store value of AlertView in iphone

Tags: iphone, uialertview

HI,

I'm aware that accessing the SMS incoming isn't possible in the iPhone SDk but could i read the alertView that is active on the iPhone (ie. new SMS alert) and store its values into a variable? Obviously this would require backgrounding but in theory could this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other stated, you cannot see the SMS message or associated alerts.

Not sure about iOS, but on other platforms (e.g. Java ME) it is possible to address an SMS to your application instead of the phone's "inbox" (default handler).  This requires that you control the server sending the SMS message.

I imagine even if you could catch an SMS targeted at your iOS app, you wouldn't.  Instead use Apple's Push Notification system.

I hesitate to type this in an iOS related question, but the Android OS makes it pretty trivial for an app to see SMS messages.  You can even be woken up as they arrive.  So, if you just want to test out some idea you have, consider that.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can access your own alerts but not those from other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot access other application's data, be it in background or not.